# Accessing webapi in 2sxc with Angular2 in DotNetNuke

Tags: angular, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I currently try to use angular2 in every possible place (already did an app with ionic2) and regarding 2sxc, I came across your angular2-heroes demo:
https://github.com/2sic/app-tutorial-angular2-heroes

I tried to find any clues online or in the 2sxc source on how to access the 2sxc webapi in angular2, the only thing I would need are the headers I suppose.

So, is there a way getting the headers into angular2, from the 2sxc api eventually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Daniel we're actually working on it just now. As of now, you should probably check out the angular1 implementation and just imitate what we did there - https://github.com/2sic/2sxc-ui/blob/master/src/js-api/angular1/2sxc4ng.js#L120-L140

Since our final solution must be very stable, we have to be sure it's the right way, so an official version will probably take another 4-8 weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the clue, my Deadline is too close tho, I need to Stick @ Angular 1 for this week, I'm looking forward to A2sxc :)